# Return primary key of inserted row using SQLAlchemy & SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert a row and retain the primary key for downstream application use. I can't seem to retrieve the value in SQLAlchemy, but seems to work fine in my database management system.

Here is the base code

```
sql = """
INSERT INTO [workflow_execution_status]([workflow], [requested_by], [requested_datetime], [experiment_id])
OUTPUT Inserted.execution_id 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
"""

with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(sql, ('test_workflow', 'test_user', datetime.datetime.now(), 0))
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

But this is the error I'm receiving:

> DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')

I'm guessing that I'm doing something incorrectly with SQLAlchemy -- hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Possibly the driver is confused by the initial row count for the insert operation. Does it work better if you use `set nocount on; INSERT INTO ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlwaysLearning's solution is correct. Append "SET NOCOUNT ON;" to the top of the query, e.g.

```
sql = """
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [workflow_execution_status]([workflow], [requested_by], [requested_datetime], [experiment_id])
OUTPUT Inserted.execution_id 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"""
```